# nothing showing in input box in IE if we type anything?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xhtml

see Name and Email input boxes in header

[see here](http://healmyptsd.com/healtest/)

Comment: my browser was hanged i couldn't edit question, now it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a CSS problem.  in IE 6 and 7, the text boxes appear lower in the page than you intended.  In IE 8, the text is appearing above the text input boxes.

EDIT:

This is because you have line-height set to 0.5px.  Setting it to the same height as the box fixes the problem.

The problem CSS is under the following:

```
#container #header #signUp INPUT
```

BTW.  In order to test other versions of IE than what you currently have installed, check out [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Comment: Modified my answer with the solution.  Remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem.